# In jquery get value from array by key name

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have One Program where i get information contains in array and i want to aceess it with using key.

Is there any Way for this ?

Here are code example :

```
jQuery("#sl_name").change(function(){
    var id = this.value;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : 'insert.php',
        type:'post',
        data:{'action': 'getById','id':id},
        success : function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });

});
```

Here variable Data contain array of user i need to access by key value like in php we can get.

If you are return print_r than use json_encode method.

Thanks In Adavance.

Comment: Question is unclear.

Comment: **alert(data["keyname"])** ?

Comment: can you show the code in `insert.php` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use alert to debug objects, you will always get `[Object object]`, use `console.log` instead:

```
jQuery("#sl_name").change(function () {
    var id = this.value;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            'action': 'getById',
            'id': id
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

            //if data is not yet a json object
            data = JSON.parse(data);

            //To access by key/prop
            console.log(data.username);

            //if data is an array:
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) console.log(data[i]);
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: agreed.. and to check the result of `console.log` check your browser's console, on Chrome right click anywhere on your page and go to "inspect element"

Comment: thanks but console.log(data.keyname); i can't get value by this way with using key name. && I am Using just for confirmation so i have used alert.

Comment: use console.log(data); first in order to check what keys are present.

Comment: when you run `console.log(data)`, what do you get in your console?

Comment: yes key are present. this is response Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [id] => 2
    [1] => Yogesh
    [fname] => Yogesh
    [2] => shishangiya.yogesh@gmail.com
    [email] => shishangiya.yogesh@gmail.com
    [3] => 123456
    [password] => 123456

Comment: sounds like your PHP is using `print_r`. If you have an array in PHP you should `json_encode` it then `echo` it

Comment: No problem. Glad I can help